# Custom AWS Config rule with Guard policy for checking User access key

Tags: amazon-iam, aws-config

I have read this artice that shows how to write a custom AWS Config rule with Guard policy:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/announcing-aws-config-custom-rules-using-guard-custom-policy/

I want to write a similar custom AWS Config rule that checks access key age. If the key age is over 60 days, I want to make it non-compliant.

My first starting point was to find the Config rule schemas for IAM Users. I found this one:
https://github.com/awslabs/aws-config-resource-schema/blob/master/config/properties/resource-types/AWS%3A%3AIAM%3A%3AUser.properties.json

But this schema does not include any details for access keys. I was hoping it will include a property such as maxAccesskeyAge.

I was hoping I could write a rule like this:

```
let maxKeyAge = 60
rule compliancecheck when 
        resourceType == "AWS::IAM::USER" {
            configuration.maxAccessKeyAge == %maxKeyAge
        }
```

But this code does not work.

How can I write a custom Config rule to check key age?
thanks

Comment: I havem't used Guard custom policies, but you may be able to solve the problem without one. Have you tried the built-in rule `access-keys-rotated`? Read it in the [AWS Config Developer Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/access-keys-rotated.html).

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues with the code. resourceType should be AWS::IAM::User (not uppercase USER)

The property that tell us about key age is configuration.createDate

So the final code should be:

```
rule compliancecheck{
 when resourceType == "AWS::IAM::User" {
            configuration.createDate ==  "2014-01-12T16:13:20.00Z"
        }
}
```

Comment: you posted this as an answer but it reads more like an edit to your original question. Are you still looking for an answer?